# D3.js Bar chart - Aligning labels with custom bar width

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a bar chart that will display dynamic data, meaning that there could be anywhere between 1-10 bars upon loading. By default, the labels correctly align to the center of each bar. However, for my bar chart I need to make the width of each bar shorter.

I've tried changing the following line of code:

```
height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

This succeeds in reducing the width of the bars but does so by reducing the overall size of the graph.

Additionally, i've tried changing the height attribute in the following code:

```
 svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("width", function(d) {return x(d.value); } )
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.label); })
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
```

This successfully resizes the bar but moves the labels out of allignment.

Can anyone help me in having the labels automatically re-align to the center of the bar when given a custom width? I've attached a link to a JSFiddle to help visualize my problem.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jop08tue/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [padding](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#band_padding) is right there, use it:

```
var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([height, 0])
    .padding(0.4);//tweak this value here
```

Here is your updated fiddle, with a padding of 0.4: https://jsfiddle.net/xLfdft2f/